# Wordpress REST API endpoint : "no such route"

Tags: wordpress, rest

I am trying to send data from Website A to Website B.

Both websites are running WordPress and I have 1 form on Website A that after it gets submitted makes a REST API POST call to Website B.

I use the following code to create the REST API Endpoint but for some reason Website B responds that there is no such route.

I am trying to access the endpoint like this: https://www.websiteb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/update_option

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_update_option_endpoint' );

function register_update_option_endpoint() {
    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', '/update_option', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'update_option_data',
    ) );
}

function update_option_data( $request ) {
    $option_name = $request->get_param( 'option_name' );
    $option_value = $request->get_param( 'option_value' );
    update_option( $option_name, $option_value );
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with WP but I would suspect your namespace might be wrong if it can't find the desired route : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/

Comment: Also - It might help to try and query directly the Website B's API directly first to make sure the routes are there etc : Something like PostMan would be user friendly to help identify the origin of the fault.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The WordPress API is there and working correctly just my endpoint does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my problem was generated by the iThemes Security plugin. Once I disable it, the code worked. I will also like to add that the update_option_data function was working, it only saved 1 option and turned the other options empty so in order to avoid this behavior I had to change my code to:

```
function update_option_data( $request ) {
    $option_name = sanitize_text_field($request->get_param( 'option_name' ));
    $option_value = sanitize_text_field($request->get_param( 'option_value' ));

    $local_site_info = get_option( 'option_page_name' );
    $local_site_info[$option_name] = $option_value;
    update_option( 'option_page_name', $local_site_info );

    return true;
}
```